# Replace empty spaces with TAB except in last column

Tags: awk, sed, tr

I have a file that looks like this.
How can I replace each empty space with a TAB except in the last column that starts with ID?

```
chr1 13513 14763 Medtr1g004950 . + JCVI gene . ID=Medtr1g004950;Note=hypothetical protein
chr1 15282 16532 Medtr1g004960 . + JCVI gene . ID=Medtr1g004960;Note=hypothetical protein
chr1 30972 32222 Medtr1g004980 . + JCVI gene . ID=Medtr1g004980;Note=hypothetical protein
```

Comment: Not my downvote. We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: I understand,  I will continue trying

Comment: Is the number of columns always the same in your files?

Comment: The number of columns is always the same in the files

Comment: Hint: So you can replace first two spaces with GNU sed: `sed 's/ /\t/; s/ /\t/' file` :-)

Comment: The hint helped me finally because further on through the file the answer was still causing issues in some lines introducing a TAB space haphazardly...I am not sure why. Ultimately I used: sed 's/ /\t/; s/ /\t/'; s/ /\t/'; s/ /\t/'; s/ /\t/'; s/ /\t/'; s/ /\t/'; s/ /\t/' file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take your pick:

```
$ sed 's/ /\t/g; s/\t/ /10' file
chr1    13513   14763   Medtr1g004950   .       +       JCVI    gene    .       ID=Medtr1g004950;Note=hypothetical protein
chr1    15282   16532   Medtr1g004960   .       +       JCVI    gene    .       ID=Medtr1g004960;Note=hypothetical protein
chr1    30972   32222   Medtr1g004980   .       +       JCVI    gene    .       ID=Medtr1g004980;Note=hypothetical protein

$ sed 's/ /\t/g; s/\t\([^\t]*\)$/ \1/' file
chr1    13513   14763   Medtr1g004950   .       +       JCVI    gene    .       ID=Medtr1g004950;Note=hypothetical protein
chr1    15282   16532   Medtr1g004960   .       +       JCVI    gene    .       ID=Medtr1g004960;Note=hypothetical protein
chr1    30972   32222   Medtr1g004980   .       +       JCVI    gene    .       ID=Medtr1g004980;Note=hypothetical protein
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{l=$NF;$NF="";gsub(" ","\t",$0);gsub(/[[:space:]]$/, "", $0);print $0,l}'  filename


chr1    13513   14763   Medtr1g004950   .       +       JCVI    gene    .       ID=Medtr1g004950;Note=hypothetical protein
chr1    15282   16532   Medtr1g004960   .       +       JCVI    gene    .       ID=Medtr1g004960;Note=hypothetical protein
chr1    30972   32222   Medtr1g004980   .       +       JCVI    gene    .       ID=Medtr1g004980;Note=hypothetical protein
```